# c++ vector pushback() & popback() functions

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector and would like to write my own functions for school purposes and im stuck.

```
void push_back(int value)
void pop_value();
```

i would like to implement functions in main like this

```
iv2.push_back(100)
iv2.push_back(101) // will cause exception to be thrown.
```

can someone please show me how to write these functions out so i can understand what they are doing. Let me know if you need more of my class.

```
class int_vector {


public:
        //deafault constructor
        int_vector() : capacity_(minCapacity_), size_(0), data_(new int[capacity_]) {
            cout << "default constructor of: " << this << "\n";
        }

...


private:


void push_back(int value) {}?
void pop_value(){}

....
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? Do you understand what a vector actually is? It is a dynamic array. Do you know how to work with arrays yet? Do you know how to add values to an array, move values around an array, and remove values from an array? How about allocating and freeing an array? A vector has to do these things

Comment: yes i do. I just would like to see the function should be formally written. So i can go through step by step whats happening in memory

Comment: Why would the second `push_back` throw an exception?

Comment: i just posted full code so you get a better understanding

Comment: @Patrickbateman there is no "formal" way to implement the functions, use what makes sense for your code. But if you knew how to do the basic things I mentioned earlier, you shouldn't need to ask about this. Pushing a value is simply a matter of 1) (re)allocating the array if its new `size` would exceed its current `capacity`, 2) inserting the value in the unused slot at the current `size`, and 3) incrementing the `size`. Popping is just removing the value from the current `size-1` slot and decrementing the `size`.

Comment: @Patrickbateman BTW, your constructors are buggy. Your `initializer_list` constructor is not allocating memory correctly, and your copy constructor is not initializing data members.

Comment: ok now i understamd push. but what am i doing wrong with pop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at how a vector is implemented at https://github.com/lnishan/vector/blob/master/vector.hpp

I hope it helps.

Comment: That vector class has a big flaw in the `operator=` implementation.  You have altered member variables *before* reallocating.  If the allocation fails, you've corrupted your class by changing member variables prematurely.  It should have used copy-swap to implement the assignment operator.

Comment: you are right.it's not my implements.I've seen it on GitHub.

Comment: Well, that's what happens when code isn't peer-reviewed.  Took me all of 30 seconds to see the issue, so who knows how many other flaws it may have.

Comment: you can read the book <<Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++>>. http://www.stroustrup.com/PPP2_Ch18.pdf ,explained how to implement a vector.

Comment: Here is the paragraph from Stroustrup: *When implementing the assignment, you could consider simplifying the code by freeing the memory for the old elements before creating the copy, but it is usually
a very good idea not to throw away information before you know that you
can replace it.* -- That is the exact mistake made by the code at the Github link.  Member variables are "thrown away", i.e. changed before the allocation is attempted.